# Parsing an XML file using DOM, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to use the DOM parser to parser an XML file from the NPR news feed. I need the titles and descriptions of the articles to appear on a GUI (which I haven't written yet, trying to get them to work with just system.out first). When trying to run this I get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at NPRDOM.NPRInfo(NPRDOM.java:26)  
    at NPRDOM.main(NPRDOM.java:9)
```

I looked up what the null pointer exception was, but I'm not entirely sure what part of this I am writing incorrectly.
Any tips or "pointers" ;P would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
//import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class NPRDOM {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NPRInfo();
    }

    public static void NPRInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
        //URL XmlFile = new URL("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001");
        DocumentBuilderFactory XmlBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder xBuilder = XmlBuilder.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xml = xBuilder.parse(new URL("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001").openStream());

        xml.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel");

        int temp = 0;
        for (temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++);
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("Current Element " + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Title : " + eElement.getAttribute("title"));
                System.out.println("Description : "+ eElement.getAttribute("description"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe just try dumping the full xml returned from xBuilder.parse(<URL>) to System.out see exactly what you're getting?  It seems like the null pointer exception right now is coming from there being no "channel" elements in the xml you're getting back.

Comment: basically you are getting `nNode` as `null` that's why `nNode.getNodeName()` raised `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the `for` loop statement:

```
for (temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++);
```

It is causing the loop to execute an empty statement, causing variable `temp` to access a `null` element in the `NodeList`.

In addition, after checking the XML feed, it seems the `title` and `description` nodes are elements inside the `channel` node, and *not* attributes. So you would need to retrieve their values using `getElementsByTagName()` instead of `getAttribute()`:

```
System.out.println("Title : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Description : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
```

Of course you should add a check on whether the children nodes exist (the above assumes a `title` node always exists).

Comment: Wow, thanks that actually fixed most of the problem, it seems now though that it is only pulling one story as opposed to all the stories on the document.

Comment: You would just need to get the "story" elements and loop over them, similar to the way you're doing. It is basically one step further in traversing the XML.

Comment: You're a huge help man, I would +1 if I could but it seems that my rep is just terrible. Haha Thanks so much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two obvious sources of NPE

```
Document xml = xBuilder.parse(new URL("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001").openStream());
if(xml==null)
   System.out.println("No XML DOM Document retrieved.");

xml.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel");
if(nList ==null)
   System.out.println("No elements with tag name channel retrieved.");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've just never worked with a DOM parser or any parser for that matter, I'll work on being more observant next time!